# How to remove UINavigationBar transparency in iOS8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, transparency

I made my `UINavigationBar` `transparent` in `ViewDidLoad()` using below code and

```
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                                                  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
    self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

This is working perfectly and i want to remove this transparency and get back old (normal ) `UINavigationBar` on `ViewDidDisappear`( ).

How do I get normal `UINavigationBar` ?

Comment: please share screen shot...

Comment: top navigation is not there (empty space ) when i reached next page

Comment: not getting your problem.. please share screenshot... also remove all code and write single line of code and then check...      [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO]

Comment: I don't see why a screen shot should be needed here. The description of what OP wants is precise enough and a screenshot wouldn't add any value.

Comment: @mmgross i think he have different problem his problem is not so clear. and if you  don't  want need of screenshot so it doesn't apply on other.

Comment: He has a translucent navigation bar and wants to make it non-translucent under certain circumstances. If you know how a translucent navigation bar looks like, why would you need a screenshot (if you don't know how it looks like, why would you even bother to comment on this question)?

Comment: @mmgross Instead of giving answer to his question why are you doing such silly thing. i require it that why  i am asking. i know you are so talented  but it don't mean that you apply your own decision on others.

Answer (score 6):

Write the below line in your code:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO]
```

And remove below code

`self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
 self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

Comment: still its transparent

Comment: Did you remove this code  self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];

Comment: You added that to make transparent and if you don't want then remove it.

Comment: ok, now it coming correctly but i can see one normal UINavigationBar and below that one transparent UINavigationBar